# Looping through Nested json object with unwanted characters

Tags: javascript

Below is a fraction of what I exported from WordPress database as .json file, I want to be able to iterate over the whole data with special attention to `statutory_fees`.

In a nutshell, I want to be able to access `st_type: Land Survey`, meanwhile, the I can currently access `pid: 25`

```
const data = [
  {
    "pid": "25",
    "plotstatus": "Completed",

    "statutory_fees": "[{\"st_type\":\"Land Survey Plan\",\"landsurveyplanamount\":\"150000\",\"landsurveyplanamountpaid\":\"0\",\"landsurveyplanfeebalance\":\"150000\",\"landsurveyplanfeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Legal Fee\",\"legalfeeamount\":\"50000\",\"legalfeeamountpaid\":\"0\",\"legalfeefeebalance\":\"50000\",\"legalfeefeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Development\\\/Electrification Fee\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeeamount\":\"200000\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeeamountpaid\":\"0\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeefeebalance\":\"200000\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeefeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Registration Form Fee\",\"registrationformfeeamount\":\"2000\",\"registrationformfeeamountpaid\":\"0\",\"registrationformfeefeebalance\":\"2000\",\"registrationformfeefeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"}]",

    "contract_of_sale": "Not Collected",
    "deed_of_assignmen": "Not Collected",
  },
  {
    "pid": "25",
    "plotstatus": "Completed",

    "statutory_fees": "[{\"st_type\":\"Land Survey Plan\",\"landsurveyplanamount\":\"150000\",\"landsurveyplanamountpaid\":\"150000\",\"landsurveyplanfeebalance\":\"0\",\"landsurveyplanfeestatus\":\"Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Legal Fee\",\"legalfeeamount\":\"50000\",\"legalfeeamountpaid\":\"50000\",\"legalfeefeebalance\":\"0\",\"legalfeefeestatus\":\"Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Development\\\/Electrification Fee\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeeamount\":\"300000\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeeamountpaid\":\"0\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeefeebalance\":\"300000\",\"development\\\/electrificationfeefeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"},{\"st_type\":\"Registration Form Fee\",\"registrationformfeeamount\":\"2000\",\"registrationformfeeamountpaid\":\"0\",\"registrationformfeefeebalance\":\"2000\",\"registrationformfeefeestatus\":\"Not Completed\"}]",

    "contract_of_sale": "Not Collected",
    "deed_of_assignmen": "Not Collected",
    
  }
]
```

I have tried the following ways:

```
let purfi = []
data.forEach(elem => {
  JSON.stringify(elem.statutory_fees).replace(/\\/g, '')
  purfi.push(elem)
})

let veri = []
purfi.forEach(a=>{
  JSON.parse(a.statutory_fees)
  veri.push(a)
})

veri.forEach(a=>{
  console.log(a.statutory_fees[0].st_type // undefined
})
```

Answer (score 2):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) over the data and parse the JSON in `statutory_fees` to get a new array of objects that you can access.

```js
const data=[{pid:"25",plotstatus:"Completed",statutory_fees:'[{"st_type":"Land Survey Plan","landsurveyplanamount":"150000","landsurveyplanamountpaid":"0","landsurveyplanfeebalance":"150000","landsurveyplanfeestatus":"Not Completed"},{"st_type":"Legal Fee","legalfeeamount":"50000","legalfeeamountpaid":"0","legalfeefeebalance":"50000","legalfeefeestatus":"Not Completed"},{"st_type":"Development\\/Electrification Fee","development\\/electrificationfeeamount":"200000","development\\/electrificationfeeamountpaid":"0","development\\/electrificationfeefeebalance":"200000","development\\/electrificationfeefeestatus":"Not Completed"},{"st_type":"Registration Form Fee","registrationformfeeamount":"2000","registrationformfeeamountpaid":"0","registrationformfeefeebalance":"2000","registrationformfeefeestatus":"Not Completed"}]',contract_of_sale:"Not Collected",deed_of_assignmen:"Not Collected"},{pid:"25",plotstatus:"Completed",statutory_fees:'[{"st_type":"Land Survey Plan","landsurveyplanamount":"150000","landsurveyplanamountpaid":"150000","landsurveyplanfeebalance":"0","landsurveyplanfeestatus":"Completed"},{"st_type":"Legal Fee","legalfeeamount":"50000","legalfeeamountpaid":"50000","legalfeefeebalance":"0","legalfeefeestatus":"Completed"},{"st_type":"Development\\/Electrification Fee","development\\/electrificationfeeamount":"300000","development\\/electrificationfeeamountpaid":"0","development\\/electrificationfeefeebalance":"300000","development\\/electrificationfeefeestatus":"Not Completed"},{"st_type":"Registration Form Fee","registrationformfeeamount":"2000","registrationformfeeamountpaid":"0","registrationformfeefeebalance":"2000","registrationformfeefeestatus":"Not Completed"}]',contract_of_sale:"Not Collected",deed_of_assignmen:"Not Collected"}];

// Iterate over the data array with `map`
// Note: `map` returns a _new_ array
const out = data.map(obj => {

  // Destructure `statutory_fees` from each object
  // along with the rest of the properties
  const { statutory_fees, ...rest } = obj;

  // And then return it parsed in a new object
  // with the rest of the properties
  return {
    ...rest,
    statutory_fees: JSON.parse(statutory_fees)
  };

});

console.log(out);
console.log(out[0].statutory_fees[0].st_type);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I didn't know that use of the spead operator in a destructuring context. Instructive! ;)

Comment: Yeah, so [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Thanks @Andy for the solution, however it worked with a very simple data, however when I applied it to my project, it returned this error                                   
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)